# Android getLocationonScreen() function is returning the location of the parent view instead of the child view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I've created a RelativeLayout within my activity, and I'm dynamically creating ImageView objects that I'm adding to the RelativeLayout using addView along with RelativeLayout.LayoutParams. When I then go to get the position of the child view, it always returns the coordinates of the parent view. Here are the pertinent parts of the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public RelativeLayout parentLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams;
    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        parentLayout = findViewById(R.id.parentRelativeLayout);
    }

    // Method to dynamically add the ImageView to the parent
    public int addObject(Drawable drawing, int x, int y) {
        ImageView newObj = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        newObj.setBackground(drawing);
        layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50);
        layoutParams.leftMargin = x;
        layoutParams.topMargin = y;
        int childIndex = parentLayout.getChildCount()-1;
        parentLayout.addView(newObj, childIndex,layoutParams);

        return childIndex;
    }

    public int[] getChildLocation(int childIndex) {
        View childView;
        int[] outlineCoord = new int[2];

        childView = parentLayout.getChildAt(childIndex);
        childView.getLocationOnScreen(outlineCoord);

        return outlineCoord;
    }

}
```

If I then add a child and attempt to retrieve the coordinates of the child view, I always get the location of the parent:

```
childIndex = addObject(getResources().getDrawable(blackcircle), 100, 200);
outlineCoord = getChildLocation(childIndex);

Log.i("LOC:", "Location of child is X: " + outlineCoord[0] + " Y: " + outlineCoord[1]);
```

I can't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you sure you are passing correct arguments to `getLocationOnScreen`.Check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLocationOnScreen(int[])

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The getLocationOnScreen method is fairly simple. You just pass it an integer array of size 2 which it uses to store the coordinates. That's the only documented argument.